# How to search via Enums Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to a write a search function for table reserving from a restaurant, I have a restaurant model:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    """
    Table Restaurant
    =======================

    This table represents a restaurant with all necessary information.
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    caterer = models.ForeignKey(Caterer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    address = models.OneToOneField(Address, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    kitchen_type = models.IntegerField(choices=KITCHEN_TYPE, null=True)
    opening_hours = models.OneToOneField(OpeningHours, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)
    parking_options = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

which has a enum for  kitchen_type:

```
KITCHEN_TYPE = [
    (1, "Turkish"),
    (2, "Italian"),
    (3, "German"),
    (4, "English"),
    (5, "Indian"),
]
```

And this is the search function in view.py:

```
def search_result(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        searched = request.POST['searched']
        result = Restaurant.objects.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=searched) | Q(address__city__icontains=searched))
        return render(request, 'search_result.html', {'searched': searched, 'result': result})
    else:
        return render(request, 'search_result.html', {})
```

So how am I able to search for **kitchen_type** in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a list of tuples I would recommend extending the `IntegerChoices` or `TextChoices` classes provided by Django. Here's an example of how you can use `IntegerChoices`:

```
>>> class KitchenType(models.IntegerChoices):
...     TURKISH = 1
...     ITALIAN = 2
...     GERMAN = 3
... 
>>> if 1 in KitchenType:
...     print(True)
... 
True
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types